# ImportError with scipy misc

Tags: python-3.x, dll, scipy

when I run this code :

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave, imresize
first = imread('aa.jpg')
sec = imresize(first, (3000,3000))
imsave('aaa.jpg',sec)
```

it shows error :

> File "_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

how can I solve this problem ????!
please help
Note : I also installed pillow

Answer (score 0):

This typically a symptom of a broken scipy installation. Best reinstall it, using whatever means you used for i stalling it in first place.